# Generate Base64 from ExcelJS WorkBook

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, base64, exceljs

I am working with ExcelJS library in NodeJS for creating a excel file.
What I need it's to generate a Base64 string from a Workbook object.

I have this code

```
let workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({});
let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(`CREReport_${origcontractid}`);
worksheet.getCell('A1').value = 'CRE evolution';
worksheet.commit();
```

but I don't know how to generate a Base64 string based on my workbook. I don't want to create a file in my disk, i want to return in my webservice a base64 string which represent the file. any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

with the file buffer you can get the base64.

```
const fileBuffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()
```

Comment: is this function create base64 or have to do after this also?

Answer (score 0):

I did this.
Just need **writebuffer** method and **create blob object using data buffer**.
Whit this, we can create **base64** string from **workbook**.

```
workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(async (data) => {
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    const base64data = reader.result;                
    console.log(base64data);
  }
});
```

Good luck